# MySQL UPDATE values with sequence 1,2,3, 

Tags: mysql, sequence

I have table with position atribute 'posit' with unknown values (in my example '0') and I want to UPDATE it to 1,2,3, ...

BEFORE:

```
 _______________
| title | posit |
|---------------|
|  test |   0   |
|-------|-------|
|  test |   0   |
|-------|-------|
|  test |   0   |
|-------|-------|
|  test |   0   |
'---------------'
```

AFTER:

```
 _______________
| title | posit |
|---------------|
|  test |   1   |
|-------|-------|
|  test |   2   |
|-------|-------|
|  test |   3   |
|-------|-------|
|  test |   4   |
'---------------'
```

Something like this

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET posit = last_updated_value() + 1 
WHERE title='test';
```

Is there any way to do it by SQL command? Note that 'posit' is not auto increment. I have only PHP solution.

Thanks 
Henry

Answer (score 3):

You have mysql as a tag, so with that you could use a user defined variable. Something like this:

```
SET @incr = 0;
SELECT @incr:=@incr+1 FROM DUAL;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html for more details.

Comment: That will only return one row, with a value of one.

Comment: It was meant as a sample, not a definitive solution. The next time you run the select, it will give you back a 2.

Comment: Thanks. You open my eyes. So this is final SQL.
SET @incr = 0;
UPDATE myTable SET posit = @incr:=@incr+1 WHERE title='test';